# GCD proof: $\gcd(a+b,a-b)\geq\gcd(a,b)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, integers

How to prove that $\gcd(a+b,a-b)\geq\gcd(a,b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers?

I'm not sure how to frame the equations and derive the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is deceptively simple. Let $d=gcd(a,b)$. That is to say $d$ is the greatest integer that divides $a$ and $b$. All we need though is that it divides both. Next, we use the fact that if $d|a$ and $d|b$ then $d|a+b$ and $d|a-b$. With this, we have that $d$ is *a* common divisor of both $a+b$ and $a-b$, and thus must be less than or equal to the *greatest* common divisor of $a+b$ and $a-b$.

Comment: Yes indeed. So $d$ might be the GCD of $a+b$ and $a-b$, but it's definitely a common divisor of both. I need more practice to be able to bridge English and Maths... Thank you.